# Which error value should I use?

Tags: c, linux, error-handling, linux-kernel

I am currently building a module for the Linux Kernel. My working revision is 3.8-rc3+. My work lead me to implement some `ioctl()` commands. As you know, my commands should return an appropriate error code to describe what went wrong during the execution. This seems quite simple, but I have a use case for which I can't figure out which error code I should return.

Basically, I want the user to be able to set cryptographic keys for a given device. My module stores the keys in a R-B tree, indexed by the devices unique identifier (a basic `int`). If the "target" device has already an entry in the tree, then this entry should be updated, otherwise, the module simply adds a newly allocated entry to the tree for that device, with the requested cryptographic key. That said, multiple things can occur while trying to set the key :

- Something inside the module might be using the cryptographic key the user wants to update : the module returns `EBUSY` error.
- There was no entry and allocation failed : `ENOMEM` error.
- The module is releasing its resources. The existing key entry might be marked for deletion (the entry has a `dying` flag to signal this) : internally I currently use `EPERM` error code, since the caller has not the "permission" to alter the entry while it's being destroyed.

As I said, for the latter case, I use `EPERM` error code, but I have the feeling it's wrong and I don't know which error code I should use for that purpose. Any advice is welcome !

*I also specified linux tag as the `ioctl()` could be used within user-space applications.*

**EDIT** : After having read through comments and answers, I think I will make it this way :

- When the module is releasing its resources, `ESHUTDOWN` will be returned.
- When only the target key is being destroyed, while the rest of the
  tree is still sane, `EACCES` will be used.

Comment: you can probably use any of,
#define EACCES 13 /* Permission denied */ 
#define EFAULT 14 /* Bad address */ 
#define EBUSY 16 /* Device or resource busy */

Comment: @KinjalPatel I cannot use `EBUSY` if I want to discriminate use case 1 from use case 3. `EFAULT` is not appropriate since the command was fed with good parameters and no segfault was prevented. `EACCES` could do the trick but I also has the feeling it's not its initial purpose. Am I right ?

Comment: yes, EACCES is generally used for user permission. but in your case i think its suitable

Comment: @KinjalPatel Since the code I make is likely to be committed for review, I want to be sure it is the cleanest possible. I would have wanted so anyway though, but this makes it even more important. Don't misunderstand my comment, I agree with you about `EACCES`, I just want to be _very very_ sure.

Comment: I'd suggest `ENXIO /* No such device or address */`, but it really doesn't matter a great deal as long as you document it.

Comment: @caf I am a bit worried since I already read a violent flamebait from Linus himself towards a maintainer that messed up with error codes ! But of course, no matter what I chose as an error code, I will document it :)

Comment: @Rerito - That was much sillier than anything you seem to be considering. He was returning ENOENT (No file or directory) from ioctl(), a command that only operates on open files. The error codes you are considering seem to be all in the realm of sanity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `ESHUTDOWN`? (Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown)

Another option is `ENXIO` (No such device or address). It's not 100% accurate since the device is still there but it conveys the meaning of the error (it's no longer usable).

A simple choice would be `ENOTSUP` (Operation not supported) but that sounds more like "method not implemented"

`EPERM` sounds better but it's usually used with "you don't have permission/rights to do this" instead of "you can't do this right now".

`ESTALE` (Stale file handle) would be nice but it's NFS related.

Comment: I missed `ESHUTDOWN`, it's very explicit despite the description seems misleading to me. Anyway, I think this is the nicest solution. Thank you for pointing that out.